# Rudin’s PMA: Theorem 6.25

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ maps $[a,b]$ into $R^k$ and if $f\inℜ(α)$ for some monotonically increasing function $α$ on $[a,b]$ then $|f|\inℜ(α)$ and
$$|\int_a^bfdα|\leq\int_a^b|f|dα.  (40)$$
Proof. If $f_1,...,f_k$ are the components of $f$, then
$$|f|=(f_1^2+...+f_k^2)^{0.5}). (41)$$
By Theorem 6.11, each of the functions $f_i^2$ belongs to $ℜ(α)$; hence so does their sum. Since $x^2$ is a continuous function of $x$, Theorem 4.17 shows that the square-root function is continuous on $[0,M]$, for every real $M$. If we apply Theorem 6.11 once more, (41) shows that $|f|\inℜ(α)$.

To prove (40), put $y=(y_1,...,y_k)$, where $y_j=\int f_jdα$. Then we have $y=\int fdα$, and
$$|y|^2=\sum y_i^2=\sum y_j \int f_jdα=\int (\sum y_jf_j)dα$$

What I do not understand here, is why is the last equation true
$\sum y_j \int f_jdα=\int (\sum y_jf_j)dα$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: linearity of integration

Comment: First pull the $y_j$ into the integral ($y_j$ is a scalar) and then pull the summation into the integral (the sum is finite).

Comment: $y_j$ is a _constant_.

Answer (score 1):

According to Theorem 6.12

> If $f_1\in\mathfrak R(\alpha)$ and $f_2\in\mathfrak R(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$, then
> $$f_1+f_2\in\mathfrak R(\alpha),$$
> $cf\in\mathfrak R(\alpha)$ for every constant c, and
> $$\int_a^b(f_1+f_2)d\alpha=\int_a^bf_1d\alpha+\int_a^bf_2d\alpha,$$
> $$\int_a^bcfd\alpha=c\int_a^bfd\alpha$$
> (By the way, I think rudin should also assume that $f\in \mathfrak R(\alpha)$ in this theorem)

Then $\displaystyle\sum y_j \int f_j d \alpha=y_1\int f_1d\alpha+...+y_k\int f_kd\alpha=\int y_1f_1d\alpha+...+\int y_kf_kd\alpha=\int (y_1f_1+...+y_kf_k)d\alpha=\int(\sum y_j f_j)d\alpha$

Noticed that $\displaystyle\int$ in the proof of theorem 6.25 means $\displaystyle\int_a^b$